Is there a way to exit/skip the current iteration of an ApplyToEach loop?
I have a scheduled flow and inside this flow i have an ApplytoEach and inside the ApplyToEach i have a condition (Condition 12). Now I want to skip the current iteration of the Apply To Each (not to skip the whole flow) in-case the condition (Condition 12) evaluate to true:-

now if i move all the actions inside the current ApplyToEach to be inside the No section of the condition, as follow:-

I will get an error that i can not have more than 8 nested levels, as my flow has a lot of nested actions..

so that why i want to keep all the actions after Conidtion-12 as-is and just skip the current ApplyToEach iteration, in case the Condition-12 evaluate to Yes.. is there a way to do so?
Thanks
